# Is it Possible To Use Changing Variables as Keys to Read JavaScript Object Values?

Tags: javascript, variables, javascript-objects

if I have an object:

```
let Cars = {Banna:'Yellow'},{Apple:'Red'}
```

Can I have a viable be a key that changes based on user input?

```
function button(userinput){
let key = userinput
}
let fruit = Cars.key
```

The Object I have in my code is much longer than this example.

Comment: `let Cars = {Banna:'Yellow'},{Apple:'Red'}` ... try `console.log(Cars)` ... what do you see?

Comment: as for your function - `key` is only accessible inside `button` function, and `let fruit = Cars.key` should be `let fruit = Cars[key]` ... but that's not evaluated more than once, and the value of `key` inside bButton` will not be relevant for the aforementioned reason